# Unity UI Line Rendering (UILineRenderer) pixelated

Tags: unity, rendering, graphics, unity-ui, line-renderer

I'm using [UILineRenderer](https://bitbucket.org/UnityUIExtensions/unity-ui-extensions/wiki/Controls/UILineRenderer) to draw curve of the map. The one thing I'm finding is that the drawing is pixelated despite adding more data points. setting the quality in game view to 4K UHD, and specifying smoothing parameters. There are sufficient number of points but the rendering is pixelated.

[image]

How can I have `MaskableGraphic` draw smooth lines?

Comment: This looks like a job for a signed distance field, so you can antialias the line in the shader based on the pixel's distance from the edge.

Comment: Have you tried turning on anti-aliasing in the project settings?